# Snow <covered> the hills. [dynamic or stative]

Tags: stative-verbs

> Snow covered the hills. ([source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cover))

**Question:** Is "covered" a dynamic verb or a stative verb?

Comment: Does it matter? The "static" or "dynamic" nature of a verb is part of its meaning, not its grammar. If you understand the meaning, then you don't need the analysis.

Comment: @JamesK I don't know whether the sentence states the state or the action.

Comment: How would these be different?  In Japanese, for example, is there a difference.

Comment: In Japanese, there is a difference. "雪が丘を覆った" expresses the action. "雪が丘を覆っていた" expresses the state.

Comment: Thank you, but that is the address of this thread.

Comment: I mean https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/345599/the-hill-was-covered-by-with-snow-dynamic-or-stative

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, it could be both dynamic and stative depending on what idea you're trying to express. If you're trying to express the idea that it snowed, and snow built up on the field, then it's dynamic since that refers to the action of snow having covered the hills. If you're trying to express the idea that there was simply a lot of snow on the hills, then it's stative.

Comment: @Thank you, Kyle Colbourne. I don't know whether the sentence states the state or the action. Isn't the sentence ambiguous to the listener/reader?

Comment: If it's a sentence like this on its own, it can be ambiguous. However, as is the case with ambiguity, it can be discerned through context.