# The hill was covered by/with snow. [dynamic or stative]

Tags: passive-voice, stative-verbs

(1) The hill **was covered by** snow.

(2) The hill **was covered with** snow.

**Question:** Is the following explanation correct?

Sentence (1) is a dynamic passive sentence.

Sentence (2) is a stative passive sentence.

Comment: The past participle always expresses state (as do adjectives formed from them).  We use **being** to add the sense of ongoing action, **is being covered**.

Comment: Thank you, but I think "He was shot in the chest" expresses an action.

Comment: But actions can be completed, in which case the state is not dynamic. Perhaps you should clarify what you meant by those terms, dynamic or stative.

Comment: Some people call sentences like "I was tired" stative passives, as a kind of "false passive". Is that what you meant? Do you mean "true passive" with "dynamic" and false passive" with "stative"? Are you asking whether "The hill was covered with snow" is a false passive and "...by snow" is a true passive?  Is your interest not  using English but analyzing English?

Comment: I don't think that "I was tired" is a passive sentence. I think "tired" is an adjective because we can say "I am **very** tired".

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't any difference in meaning, and both could be used in the same situation. The use of such expressions be used to describe a snow-covered hill.

You could probably force a "dynamic" interpretation by giving a time frame

> Between 6and 8pm the hill was covered with snow and became inaccessible to cars.

Or you could force a static interpretation:

> I looked around, the hill was covered by snow and it would be a long walk to the top.